How to avoid TestCafe automatically replace href='javascript:...' to href='javascript:parent.__proc$Html(window,...); '
In some scenario in the test case, we need to keep
href='javascript:foo'
but TestCafe will automatically replace it to
href='javascript:parent.__proc$Html(window,foo); '
Is there a way to avoid it?
href='javascript:...' shouldn't be replaced.
